# How to check multiple $.post has been send and result has been fetched on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my javascript code when someone change option and click on Go. it's change property for multiple items. I see the save button and edit button for every item.

so I manually clicked the button  after change the select and on the click of Go.

```
for (var i = 0; i < checked.length; i++) {
        var cur = checked[i];
        $(cur).parents('tr').find('.transaction-category-wrapper .select2').val(catId);
        $(cur).parents('tr').find('.transaction-verify-wrapper .btn-save').click();
    }
```

Now problem is I want to refresh the page, but after making sure that response has been come to the page. How I can achieve it.

I am thinking to implement the setTimeout but it wouldn't be good option in case of server doesn't has executed and timeout just refresh the page.

Is jQuery have some property which let me know that javascript request has been complete and response has been received.

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-save', function () {
                 // val logic

                $.post("/Entries/AddEntries", val, function (r) {
                    enableTooltip();
                });
            });
```

Comment: @31piy that post request send in another jquery event, how I can get that promise in my function, I want to wait until all post request got response.

Comment: You're already using the `success` callback which is exactly what you've asked for *"let me know that the request has been completed and response has been received"*.  So it's not clear what the issue is.  If you want to check a request outside of this, then you use the `jqXHR.readyState` that `$.post` returns.

Comment: @freedomn-m  that button save work when you click save. I have a big dropdown list on top which you just choose and check the item and press save. this should click on save and I am trying to refresh the page once every btn-save clicked > request gone > response come.

Comment: Why not use ajax to 'refresh' your page?  Then you don't need to wait / disrupt your UX.   User clicks 1st save.. page waits.. user takes time to select 2nd option and is about to click save... 1st completes... whole page reloads resetting 2nd option... user gets annoyed.

Comment: Edit makes more sense, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since every click generates a post request. You need to keep track of all those requests in an array and then wait for them to resolve. So, your code should look like:

```
var requests = [];
$(document).on('click', '.btn-save', function () {
             // val logic
            requests.push($.post("/Entries/AddEntries"));
        });
Promise.all(requests).then((data) => {do something});
```

Comment: every button click generate a seprate $.post, please check comment on another answer

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta please update your *question* as there is no (obvious) mention of multiple `$.post` requests in the *question* (just mention of multiple buttons, but not that you need the response of all of them).  We should not be expected to review every comment on every answer.

Comment: @ApoorvJoshi I am manually clicked it from my javascript function, how I can do this same in that loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.then` to handle success and failure cases of your AJAX requests:

```
$.post("your_url", { ... })
  .then(function() {
    // If succeeded
  }, function() {
    // If failed
  });
```

`.post` returns a jQuery [`deferred`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/) object, which can be responded with a [`.then()`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) handler. The first argument of `.then` is considered as a success handler, and the second one is a failure handler.

In case of multiple AJAX calls, you can use [`$.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to take action when all the AJAX calls are done.

```
$.when($.post( ... ), $.post( ... ))
  .then(function() {
    // If all AJAX calls succeed
  }, function() {
    // If any of the call fails
  });
```

Comment: I clicked the button and that click fire the event, so all $.post is separated.  how I can join it like given code.

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta -- Can you post the code which actually does this?

Comment: please check the post.

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta -- So you can write a `then` handler in your `$.post`. It will be called once your AJAX call is complete.